# Split data in intervals of pre defined lenth, R

Tags: r, time-series, intervals

I have a data set on the form below:

| Id | START DATE | END DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 2000-03-02 | 2021-01-01 |

I would like to split in 90 days interval from start to end date. I might be able to find a work around, but since I need to perform it multiple times, i am looking for a relatively simple code.
I am thinking do.call might be the way to go?

The last interval can be less than 90 days in case the ending interval does not fit with a 90 day period.

| Id | START DATE | END DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-31 |
| 1 | 2020-03-31 | 2020-06-29 |
| ... |  |  |
| 2 | 2000-03-02 | 2000-05-31 |

I got some very good suggestions for solutions, unfortunate i do not have access to the updated version of dplyr, and thus not the `reframe()`function.

I found a solution but any other solutions is still very welcome

Comment: "*I found a solution but any other solutions is still very welcome*" -> what is it? How are the currently provided answer answering (or not) the question?

Comment: I put the solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, however I dont think it is a very pretty one:

Assume `dt` is my data table, the following whileloop will solve the problem using the `data.table` package.
Before running the code i check that all end dates fall after start date.

```
continue <- TRUE
dt[,add_row:=end-start>90]
while(continu==TRUE{
dt1 <- dt[add_row==TRUE]
dt2 <- dt[add_row==TRUE]
dt3 <- dt[add_row==FALSE]

# dt1 updated with new enddate
d1[,end:=start+90]
#dt2 updated with new start
dt2[,start:=start+90]
#dt3 contains individuals not to be updated
dt <- rbind[dt1,dt2,dt2]

#check if loop should continue
dt[,add_row:=end-start>90]
continue <- any(tmp[,add_row])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create a little helper that expands a single `start` / `end` pair and use it in `dplyr::reframe()`. You do have to run this rowwise over your data, so it will be a little slow if you have a ton of rows, but I'm not sure there is any other way to do it.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(rlang)

df <- tibble(
  id = c(1L, 2L),
  start = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2000-03-02")),
  end = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-01"))
)

expand <- function(from, to) {
  # Generate sequence by 90 days, ensuring `to` is retained
  x <- seq(from, to, by = 90)
  x <- unique(c(x, to))
  
  # Safely diff the sequence into start/end
  size <- length(x)
  start <- seq2(1L, size - 1L)
  end <- seq2(2L, size)
  start <- x[start]
  end <- x[end]
  
  # Return in a data frame that `reframe()` can unpack
  data.frame(start = start, end = end)
}

df %>%
  reframe(expand(start, end), .by = id)
#> # A tibble: 90 × 3
#>       id start      end       
#>    <int> <date>     <date>    
#>  1     1 2020-01-01 2020-03-31
#>  2     1 2020-03-31 2020-06-29
#>  3     1 2020-06-29 2020-09-27
#>  4     1 2020-09-27 2020-12-26
#>  5     1 2020-12-26 2021-01-01
#>  6     2 2000-03-02 2000-05-31
#>  7     2 2000-05-31 2000-08-29
#>  8     2 2000-08-29 2000-11-27
#>  9     2 2000-11-27 2001-02-25
#> 10     2 2001-02-25 2001-05-26
#> # ℹ 80 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the very nice answer, unfortunate it turns out that i do not have access to the updated version of dplyr containing the reframe function. Do you have any suggestions to another function that might so the same?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to use `seq` from `start` to `end` by 90 days, for each `id`, keeping the `end` column. Then, modify the `end` column to the earlier date between `end` and 90 days from `start` to prevent going beyond the end date.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  reframe(end, start = seq.Date(start, end, "90 days"), .by = id) %>%
  mutate(end = pmin(end, start + 90), .by = id) %>%
  relocate(end, .after = start)
```

**Output**

```
      id start      end       
   <int> <date>     <date>    
 1     1 2020-01-01 2020-03-31
 2     1 2020-03-31 2020-06-29
 3     1 2020-06-29 2020-09-27
 4     1 2020-09-27 2020-12-26
 5     1 2020-12-26 2021-01-01
 6     2 2000-03-02 2000-05-31
 7     2 2000-05-31 2000-08-29
 8     2 2000-08-29 2000-11-27
 9     2 2000-11-27 2001-02-25
10     2 2001-02-25 2001-05-26
# ℹ 80 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

**Edit**: Alternatively, without using `reframe` you can use `map_dfr` after `group_split`. This should provide the same result.

```
df %>%
  group_split(id) %>%
  map_dfr(~tibble(
    start = seq.Date(.x$start, .x$end, "90 days"),
    end = .x$end
  ), .id = "id") %>%
  mutate(end = pmin(end, start + 90))
```

Comment: Thanks for the very nice answer, unfortunate it turns out that i do not have access to the updated version of dplyr containing the `reframe` function. Do you have any suggestions to another function that might so the same?

Comment: @Kirsten See edit above - this might be an alternative without `reframe`...